# Combine gitlab heatmap commit with github account

Tags: github, gitlab, heatmap

I have been using my university private gitlab for a while. I have a lot of commit that can be shown like this [Gitlab commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i478.png)

I cannot give the link to my gitlab to potential recruiter. So I decided to create a github and put my repositories there.

On my github I create a new repo and locally I just do:

```
git remote add origin2 git@github.com:mylogin/new_repo.git

git branch -M main

git push origin2 -u main
```

I can see the commit inside the repo, but on my github heat map it is showing as one big commit. I want it to show all my previous commit inside my github.

I don't know if it possible.
Please help.

Comment: Although you will use Git to update repositories on both GitHub and GitLab, this isn't really a *Git* issue, as Git doesn't have heatmaps or network graphs. So any GitHub solution will be GitHub-specific. (I don't know how GitHub implements this, but perhaps they use push date instead of looking at all the commits?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you see on Github is not commit, it is a event that you join Github.

Just like:
[image]

Accroding to [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-graphs-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#your-local-git-commit-email-isnt-connected-to-your-account):

> Commits must be made with an email address that is connected to your account on GitHub.com, or the GitHub-provided noreply email address provided to you in your email settings, in order to appear on your contributions graph.

So, you can **add email address which you commit on Gitlab to your Github account**. After this, the contributions will be counted and shown.

Follow this guide to set up your commit email address on Github:
https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-email-preferences/setting-your-commit-email-address#setting-your-commit-email-address-on-github

Comment: Indeed it was the email that was missing